# What is PostgreSQL explain telling me exactly?

Tags: postgresql

MySQL's explain output is pretty straightforward. PostgreSQL's is a little more complicated. I haven't been able to find a good resource that explains it either.

Can you describe what exactly explain is saying or at least point me in the direction of a good resource?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

[Explaining_EXPLAIN.pdf](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Image:Explaining_EXPLAIN.pdf) could help too.

Comment: I am mystified why people think slide decks make good technical documentation. A video of the talk might be helpful, but the information density of that slide deck is very close to zero. In the first six slides (1/5th of the total), there is exactly 1 sentence of technical content: "• EXPLAIN works on any DML not just SELECT (ie UPDATE, DELETE, and INSERT)". My biggest misunderstanding is what "startup" time means, and that's not explained anywhere in these ~30 slides.

Answer (score 147):

The part I always found confusing is the startup cost vs total cost. I Google this every time I forget about it, which brings me back to here, which doesn't explain the difference, which is why I'm writing this answer.  This is what I have gleaned from the [Postgres `EXPLAIN` documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/using-explain.html), **explained as I understand it.**

Here's an example from an application that manages a forum:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM post LIMIT 50;

Limit  (cost=0.00..3.39 rows=50 width=422)
  ->  Seq Scan on post  (cost=0.00..15629.12 rows=230412 width=422)
```

Here's the graphical explanation from PgAdmin:

[image: graphical explanation of first query]

*(When you're using PgAdmin, you can point your mouse at a component to read the cost details.)*

The cost is represented as a tuple, e.g. the cost of the `LIMIT` is `cost=0.00..3.39` and the cost of sequentially scanning `post` is `cost=0.00..15629.12`. The first number in the tuple is the *startup cost* and the second number is the *total cost*. Because I used `EXPLAIN` and not `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, these costs are estimates, not actual measures.

- *Startup cost* is a tricky concept. It doesn't just represent the amount of time before that component *starts*. It represents the amount of time between when the component starts executing (reading in data) and when **the component outputs its first row**.
- *Total cost* is the entire execution time of the component, from when it begins reading in data to when it finishes writing its output.

As a complication, each "parent" node's costs includes the cost's of its child nodes. In the text representation, the tree is represented by indentation, e.g. `LIMIT` is a parent node and `Seq Scan` is its child. In the PgAdmin representation, the arrows point from child to parent — the direction of the flow of data — which might be counterintuitive if you are familiar with graph theory.

The documentation says that costs are inclusive of all child nodes, but notice that the total cost of the parent `3.39` is much smaller than the total cost of it's child `15629.12`. Total cost is not inclusive because a component like `LIMIT` doesn't need to process its entire input. See the `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tenk1 WHERE unique1 < 100 AND unique2 > 9000 LIMIT 2;` example in [Postgres `EXPLAIN` documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/using-explain.html).

In the example above, startup time is zero for both components, because neither component needs to do any processing before it starts writing rows: a sequential scan reads the first row of the table and emits it. The `LIMIT` reads its first row and then emits it.

When would a component need to do a lot of processing before it can start to output any rows? There are a lot of possible reasons, but let's look at one clear example. Here's the same query from before but now containing an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY body LIMIT 50;

Limit  (cost=23283.24..23283.37 rows=50 width=422)
  ->  Sort  (cost=23283.24..23859.27 rows=230412 width=422)
        Sort Key: body
        ->  Seq Scan on post  (cost=0.00..15629.12 rows=230412 width=422)
```

And graphically:

[image: graphical explanation of second query]

Once again, the sequential scan on `post` has no startup cost: it starts outputting rows immediately. But the sort has a significant startup cost `23283.24` because it has to *sort the entire table before it can output even a single row*. The total cost of the sort `23859.27` is only slightly higher than the startup cost, reflecting the fact that once the entire dataset has been sorted, the sorted data can be emitted very quickly.

Notice that the startup time of the `LIMIT` `23283.24` is exactly equal to the startup time of the sort. This is not because `LIMIT` itself has a high startup time. It actually has zero startup time by itself, but `EXPLAIN` rolls up all of the child costs for each parent, so the `LIMIT` startup time includes the sum startup times of its children.

This rollup of costs can make it difficult to understand the execution cost of each individual component. For example, our `LIMIT` has zero startup time, but that's not obvious at first glance. For this reason, several other people linked to [explain.depesz.com](http://explain.depesz.com/), a tool created by Hubert Lubaczewski (a.k.a. depesz) that helps understand `EXPLAIN` by — among other things — subtracting out child costs from parent costs. He mentions some other complexities in [a short blog post](http://www.depesz.com/2008/12/04/explaindepeszcom/) about his tool.

Comment: Thank you for this. I would also like to add an explain visualizer that does an even better job of displaying the output (imo). http://tatiyants.com/pev

Comment: Great answer.  And your comment that the startup cost *includes time to first row returned* helped me understand why the startup cost for the Sort wasn't just 15629.12.

Comment: "*Total cost is the entire execution time of the component,*" - no, it's not. The cost value does not represent "execution time". You can only see the execution time if you using `explain (analyze)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name tell me you didn’t read my whole post without telling me you didn’t read my whole post 

Comment: I did read the whole post. But referring to the cost as "execution time" is simply not correct. In the rest of the answer you use the "cost thing" correctly, but in those two bullet points the reference to "execution time" is simply wrong. The cost does not represent a "time unit"

Comment: From the post that you read in whole: "Because I used EXPLAIN and not EXPLAIN ANALYZE, these costs are estimates, not actual measures."

Comment: @MarkE.Haase - This is a GREAT answer. Thanks for the detail. One minor question, mostly curiosity - what is the _unit_ "cost" is measuring? CPU cycles? DB operations? Bytes? It's obvious that a jump like `1569.79..20365.06` is steep, but how steep? How much "cost" is added in something like `45945.86..46957.24`?

Comment: Very nice answer !

Comment: @cautionbug "The most critical part of the display is the estimated statement execution cost, which is the planner's guess at how long it will take to run the statement (**measured in cost units that are arbitrary, but conventionally mean disk page fetches**). " from https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-explain.html .

Comment: I do agree with @a_horse_with_no_name that since the "cost" is not measured by  "time", phrasing like "xxx time" should be avoided as much as possible in case of confusion.  I read your whole post :).

Answer (score 44):

It executes from most indented to least indented, and I believe from the bottom of the plan to the top. (So if there are two indented sections, the one farther down the page executes first, then when they meet the other executes, then the rule joining them executes.)

The idea is that at each step there are 1 or 2 datasets that arrive and get processed by some rule.  If just one dataset, that operation is done to that data set.  (For instance scan an index to figure out what rows you want, filter a dataset, or sort it.) If two, the two datasets are the two things that are indented further, and they are joined by the rule you see. The meaning of most of the rules can be reasonably easily guessed (particularly if you have read a bunch of explain plans before), however you can try to verify individual items either by looking in the documentation or (easier) by just throwing the phrase into Google along with a few keywords like `EXPLAIN`.

This is obviously not a full explanation, but it provides enough context that you can usually figure out whatever you want. For example consider this plan from an actual database:

```
explain analyze
select a.attributeid, a.attributevalue, b.productid
from orderitemattribute a, orderitem b
where a.orderid = b.orderid
and a.attributeid = 'display-album'
and b.productid = 'ModernBook';

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 Merge Join  (cost=125379.14..125775.12 rows=3311 width=29) (actual time=841.478..841.478 rows=0 loops=1)
   Merge Cond: (a.orderid = b.orderid)
   ->  Sort  (cost=109737.32..109881.89 rows=57828 width=23) (actual time=736.163..774.475 rows=16815 loops=1)
         Sort Key: a.orderid
         Sort Method:  quicksort  Memory: 1695kB
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on orderitemattribute a  (cost=1286.88..105163.27 rows=57828 width=23) (actual time=41.536..612.731 rows=16815 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((attributeid)::text = 'display-album'::text)
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on (cost=0.00..1272.43 rows=57828 width=0) (actual time=25.033..25.033 rows=16815 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((attributeid)::text = 'display-album'::text)
   ->  Sort  (cost=15641.81..15678.73 rows=14769 width=14) (actual time=14.471..16.898 rows=1109 loops=1)
         Sort Key: b.orderid
         Sort Method:  quicksort  Memory: 76kB
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on orderitem b  (cost=310.96..14619.03 rows=14769 width=14) (actual time=1.865..8.480 rows=1114 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((productid)::text = 'ModernBook'::text)
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on id_orderitem_productid  (cost=0.00..307.27 rows=14769 width=0) (actual time=1.431..1.431 rows=1114 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((productid)::text = 'ModernBook'::text)
 Total runtime: 842.134 ms
(17 rows)
```

Try reading it for yourself and see if it makes sense.

What I read is that the database first scans the `id_orderitem_productid` index, using that to find the rows it wants from `orderitem`, then sorts that dataset using a quicksort (the sort used will change if data doesn't fit in RAM), then sets that aside.

Next, it scans `orditematt_attributeid_idx` to find the rows it wants from `orderitemattribute` and then sorts that dataset using a quicksort.

It then takes the two datasets and merges them.  (A merge join is a sort of "zipping" operation where it walks the two sorted datasets in parallel, emitting the joined row when they match.)

As I said, you work through the plan inner part to outer part, bottom to top.

Answer (score 26):

There is an online helper tool available too, [Depesz](http://www.depesz.com/), which will highlight where the expensive parts of the analysis results are.

also has one, here's the [same results](http://explain.depesz.com/s/DN), which to me make it clearer where the problem is.

Comment: explain-analyze.info seems to be down, but I concur that 
http://explain.depesz.com/ is very helpful.

Answer (score 14):

[PgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/) will show you a graphical representation of the explain plan. Switching back and forth between the two can really help you understand what the text representation means.  However, if you just want to know what it is going todo, you may be able to just always use the GUI.

Answer (score 6):

[PostgreSQL's official documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/using-explain.html) provides an interesting, thorough explanation on how to understand explain's output.

Answer (score 0):

If you install pgadmin, there's an Explain button that as well as giving the text output draws diagrams of what's happening, showing the filters, sorts and sub-set merges that I find really useful to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

[dalibo/pev2](https://github.com/dalibo/pev2) is a visualizer tool which is very helpful.

Its available here - https://explain.dalibo.com/

Postgres Explain Visualizer 2 (PEV2) looks similar to [pev](https://tatiyants.com/pev/#/plans/new). However pev is not actively maintained.

> This project is a rewrite of the excellent Postgres Explain Visualizer
> (pev). Kudos go to Alex Tatiyants.
>
> The pev project was initialy written in early 2016 but seems to be
> abandoned since then. There was no activity at all for more than 3
> years and counting though there are several issues open and relevant
> pull requests pending.

[image]