# Postgresql OR conditions with an empty subquery

Tags: postgresql

How can I optimize a query whose WHERE conditions include a check for user_id = X OR user_id IN (some subquery that might return no results)

In my example below, queries 1 and 2 are both extremely fast (< 1 ms), but query 3, which is simply an OR of the conditions in queries 1 and 2, is much slower (50 ms)

Can somebody please explain why query 3 is so slow, and in general what types of query optimization strategies should I be pursuing to avoid this problem? I realize the subquery in my example could easily be eliminated, but in real life sometimes subqueries seem like the least complicated way to get the data I want.

relevant code and data:

posts data
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4597000/StackOverflow/sanitized_posts.csv

users data
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4597000/StackOverflow/sanitized_users.csv

```
# from the shell:
# > createdb test

CREATE TABLE posts (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  created_by_id integer NOT NULL,
  created_at integer NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX index_posts ON posts (created_by_id, created_at);
CREATE INDEX index_posts_2 ON posts (created_at);

CREATE TABLE users (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  login varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX index_users ON users (login);

COPY posts FROM '/path/to/sanitized_posts.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV;
COPY users FROM '/path/to/sanitized_users.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV;


-- queries:

-- query 1, fast:
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM posts WHERE created_by_id = 123 LIMIT 100;

-- query 2, fast:
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM posts WHERE created_by_id IN (SELECT id FROM users WHERE login = 'nobodyhasthislogin') LIMIT 100;

-- query 3, slow:
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM posts WHERE created_by_id = 123 OR created_by_id IN (SELECT id FROM users WHERE login = 'nobodyhasthislogin') LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: Why run EXPLAIN ANALYZE and then not provide the information? Also, is there any reason why you're not just doing a join?

Comment: queries 1 and 2 return in less than 1 ms, query 3 takes 50 ms. I didn't include the query plans because those take a lot of text, but you can fully reproduce my example with the data/code provided

Comment: 1) Did you run 'vacuum analyze` after the import? statistics can be a great help for the optimiser/planner. 2) in (almost) all cases, `EXISTS (...)` is superior to `IN(...)`, Basically, because it can avoid a sort pass/removing duplicates. 3) inspect/show us the plan (just put `explain analyze` in front of the actual query)

Answer (score 2):

Split the query (edited):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM posts p WHERE p.created_by_id = 123 
    union    
    SELECT * FROM posts p
    WHERE 
      EXISTS ( SELECT TRUE FROM users WHERE id = p.created_by_id AND login = 'nobodyhasthislogin')
  ) p
  LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: this query produces the same results as query 3, but it is just as slow (50 ms)

Comment: changed my answer, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time in this particular query is related to an index scan.  Here is a query goes at it from a different angle to avoid this, but should return equivalent results.

```
SELECT posts.* FROM users JOIN posts on posts.created_by_id=users.id WHERE users.id=123 or login='nobodyhasthislogin'
```

This selects from the users table, doing the filter once, and then joins posts onto that.

I realize that the question is about tips for optimization, not really this specific query.  To answer that, my suggestion is to run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and read up on interpreting the results, - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117262/what-is-postgresql-explain-telling-me-exactly) answer was helpful to me.

Comment: Postgres executes uncorrelated subqueries once for each record found in the main query?

Comment: I didn't read the query plan closely enough.  Looks like most of the time involved in the original query is related to an index scan of posts_pkey.  I've edited my post to reflect that, but I'll investigate it in more detail later.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT  * 
FROM    posts
WHERE   created_by_id IN (
           SELECT 123
           UNION ALL
           SELECT id FROM
           users  WHERE
           login  = 'nobodyhasthislogin') LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: `IN ()` is not the most officient solution. Another disadvantage is Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 17kB. How we didn't see the simplest of all - `JOIN`. `Scott S`'s answer seems to be the way to go as long as there's is no `NULL` values in `created_by_id` column.

Comment: Can you explain why IN is not efficient in Postgres? I'm coming from an Oracle background where it would probably be transformed to a hash join, and the same transformation seems to occur in Postgres 9.1. The difference I've observed is that the subquery result tends to always be used as the hash table which can tend towards inefficiency if the subquery data set is the larger one. But the IN itself doesn't seem to me to be problematic unless I'm missing something?