# Width details in PostgreSQL EXPLAIN command

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL documentation states that in `explain` command, the `width` parameter is the `estimated width of each row`.

1. How is this width calculated (please mention the PostgreSQL `.c` file where this calculation is done)?
2. Does it use the `avg_width` values for each column from `pg_statistic` table?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is PostgreSQL explain telling me exactly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117262/what-is-postgresql-explain-telling-me-exactly)

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov I went through the answers. They explain `explain` in detail but do not give me information regarding `width`. I didn't find my answer in that. If you could point me where in the answers, the `width` details are discussed, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?
http://doxygen.postgresql.org/commands_2analyze_8c_source.html and
http://doxygen.postgresql.org/plannodes_8h_source.html#l00103

Comment: Yes I knew it was plan_width. I didn't know how it was calculated. I just figured out that it uses the `avg_width` in pg_statistics, for each column in the select list to determine that `plan_width`.